# Hide/show the content of a div using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, togglebutton

I am working on a news website and trying to show the full content of news article on click of a button.My code is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#toggle-news-content").click(function(){
                    $("#news-content").fadeToggle(300);
                    if($("#toggle-news-content").text()=="More")
                        $("#toggle-news-content").text("Less");
                    else
                        $("#toggle-news-content").text("More");           
                });
               });
        </script>

            <div id="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
            <div id="news-content" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
            <button id="toggle-news-content">More</button>


            <div id="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
            <div id="news-content" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
            <button id="toggle-news-content">More</button>
```

Problem is when I click on the "More" button of news 1 the script is working. But it's doing nothing when I click "More" button of news 2.
As the number of news is dynamic may vary time to time. Can anyone debug this code(Here I'm showing the code that causing the problem)

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ids

Answer (score -1):

First, you're using the same id in multiple elements. You shouldn't do that, because `id`is designed to be unique in the DOM. Change it for classes...

```
<div class="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
<div class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>

<div class="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
<div class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>
```

Then, when you click a button you have to select its related `div.news-content`, because that's what you want to show/hide. You can use `prev()`...

```
$(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
    $(this).prev("div.news-content").fadeToggle(300);
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "More" ? 'Less' : "More");
});
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

An `id` should be unique, instead use classes.

Then inside the function you can use `$(this)` to manipulate the affected element.

Please note that it now HIDES the content and shows LESS. I would switch that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('.news-content').fadeToggle(300);
    if ($(this).text() == "More")
      $(this).text("Less");
    else
      $(this).text("More");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-heading">
  <h3>news 2 heading</h3>
</div>
<div id="news-content1" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>


<div class="news-heading">
  <h3>news 2 heading</h3>
</div>
<div id="news-content2" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the most easier and elegant solution to your question. I changed your button ID for class and made the `html()` toggle with a ternary opetaror:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
        $(this).prev(".news-content").fadeToggle(300);
        $(this).html() == "More" ? $(this).html('Less') : $(this).html('More');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
            <div id="news-content" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
            <button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>


            <div id="news-heading"><h3>news 2 heading</h3></div>
            <div id="news-content" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
            <button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have unique **id** on your webpage use classes instead.

You have **dynamic** content news adding to your webpage use **jquery** [**`on`**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) handler with click event.

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

It can handle events for dynamic content as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-news-content").on("click", function() {
    $(this).prev(".news-content").fadeToggle(300);
    if ($(this).text() == "More"){
      
      $(this).text("Less");
      }
    else
      $(this).text("More");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="news-heading1">
  <h3>news 2 heading</h3>
</div>
<div id="news-content1" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>


<div id="news-heading2">
  <h3>news 2 heading</h3>
</div>
<div id="news-content2" class="news-content">news 2 content</div>
<button class="toggle-news-content">More</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

firstly, you shouldn't have same `id` in two or more elements, you should use `class`

replace `id="news-heading"` with `class="news-heading"`

and `id="toggle-news-content"` with `class="toggle-news-content"`

then, it's really simple, use this script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle-news-content").click(function() {
        var content = $(this).prev();
        $(this).text(content.is(':visible')?'Show':'Less');
        content.toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why my correct & tested answer get the downvote? :( Why all answers here got the downvote? We're all going to help the asker.

Comment: Probably while we didn't search for the duplicate question ...